# sending a JSON from the client, and the backend receives it as null ([httpGet])

Tags: c#

From the client in angular.js I am sending this json:

```
{"variable": "something"}
```

I am learning to create web services using visual studio c #, and whenever I have tried to send a JSON, I do it in the same way as I am doing, and they are always received (The problem is in the backend, I am sure). When making the web request, the received JSON is always null. How can I solve that?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace pruebaservicioweb.Controllers
{
   public class EstudianteController : ApiController
   {
    [HttpGet]
     public dynamic ReadJSON([FromBody] dynamic  parameter)
     {
        string json = parameter.variable;
        return json;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Please add the code that makes the request too :)

Comment: okay... Updating..

Comment: I don't think web api likes having the `dynamic` keyword in action method signatures.

Comment: And also - what about exception handling?  Can you log those somewhere? you might (i think definitely) be getting an exception

Comment: Get requests (normally) do not have a message body. You should be using POST.

Comment: `        private void LogAPIException(Exception ex)
        {
            using (EventLog eLog = new EventLog("Application"))
            {
                eLog.Source = "Application"; 
                eLog.WriteEntry(ex.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error);
            }
        } 
`....Add this function to your catch statement...Its 'gross' but it works :)  Sorry I cannot get the formatting better

Comment: @BrandonMiller  Aha ...Is that what the [FromBody] does?  force it to take the object from the Body?  Makes sense that GET won't work...GET is great for browser testing but YES I agree - use POST for objects

Comment: Per the spec, GET requests *can* have a message body, but servers are expected to ignore it.

Comment: @Grantly Yeah, that is exactly what it does lol. I agree with you though - I love using GET when testing, but who wants to read JSON from a URL? lol

Comment: ...Still waiting for the REQUEST (calling) code...

Comment: @Amy, good catch! I honestly didn't know until about 5 minutes ago that GET could even have a body in the request, but apparently CURL supports this functionality?

Comment: @Amy - Thanks for the info....Any chance you can post a link of the spec?

Comment: @BrandonMiller I can't answer that, I haven't used linux (and cURL) in a few years, but it wouldn't surprise me if it does support GET bodies.  [GET with bodies is discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body)

Comment: @Grantly The answer I linked to in my previous comment has a few links into the spec.

Comment: Wow! You learn something new every day! Thank you Amy (:

Comment: Consider using Fiddler4 to monitor your HTTP traffic.  Invaluable for this type of development. 

Are you setting the ContentType to "application/json"?